# Python: chose between two lists element wise based on a condition on the elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists:

```
a = [1,-1,-1, 2,-1]
b = [3, 5, 4, 6, 7]
```

I want to get a new list `c` with values `b` if `a == -1` else `0`.

```
c = [0, 5, 4, 0, 7]
```

Comment: `c = [val_b if val_a == -1 else 0 for val_a, val_b in zip(a, b)]`, surprisingly I don't find an obvious duplicate…

Comment: I see lists - not arrays. There doesn't seem to be any replacement - just a new list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with a ternary:

```
c = [val_b if val_a == -1 else 0 for val_a, val_b in zip(a, b)]
```

Output:

```
[0, 5, 4, 0, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

List comp + enumerate:

```
a = [1,-1,-1, 2,-1]
b = [3, 5, 4, 6, 7]
[b[x] if a[x]==-1 else 0 for x,y in enumerate(a)]

#[0, 5, 4, 0, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
a = [1, -1, -1, 2, -1]
b = [3, 5, 4, 6, 7]
c = []

i = 0

while i < len(a):
    if a[i] == -1:
        c.append(b[i])
    else:
        c.append(0)
    i += 1

print(c)
```

Comment: Good basic solution using a loop. For such cases where we need an index and a value, we can use `for index, value in enumerate(values)`. See [Using Python’s enumerate()](https://realpython.com/python-enumerate/#using-pythons-enumerate).